# How can i fix bootstrap carousel with mouseenter and mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have tried to create a bootstrap carousel, that is when mouseenter it slide and when mouseleave it stop. it working but i want when i leave mouse from the image it will be show the first image.please help me how can i do this?

```js
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(".carousel-prdt").on("mouseenter",function() {
             $(this).carousel('cycle');
          }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).carousel('pause');
         });
 
 
 </script>
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  
   <div id="" class="carousel-prdt slide carousel-fade" data-pause="true" data-interval="2000">`
    <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="prdt-img"> 
          <img src="img/multislide-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
         </div>
        </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
       <div class="prdt-img"> 
        <img src="img/multislide-3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="prdt-img"> 
         <img src="img/multislide-4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you add link to your carousel library?

Comment: yes i add link to my carousel  library

Answer (score 0):

> but i want when i leave mouse from the image it will be show the first image

On the `mouseleave` event you can set the current slide using the `index` of the slides--zero (0) in this case being the first slide.

Also, in a snippet, you do not need to add the `<script>` tag to the JavaScript panel section.

Select **Run code snippet** to try it out below.

```js
$(".carousel-prdt").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).carousel('cycle');
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  // go to first slide (zero index)
  $(this).carousel(0);
  $(this).carousel('pause');
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="" class="carousel-prdt slide carousel-fade" data-pause="true" data-interval="2000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="prdt-img">
          <img src="img/multislide-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="prdt-img">
          <img src="img/multislide-3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="prdt-img">
          <img src="img/multislide-4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry about missing the real question. The answer has been updated.